# How to generate only positive numbers (see what I mean below)

Tags: java

So I wrote this very simple program that asks the user to keep guessing numbers until they guess the correct number, and it will tell them if the number they picked is too low or high. The problem i'm having is the numbers were only supposed to be randomly generated 1 through 100 but java took that as -100 through 100. Anyway I was wondering how to only get it to return positive numbers.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GameMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int guess = 101;
        Random r = new Random();

        int answer = r.nextInt()%101;

        System.out.println("Whats the number?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        while (guess!=answer) {
            guess = input.nextInt();

            if (guess > answer) {
                System.out.println("Too high!");
            }
            else if (guess < answer){
                System.out.println("Too low!");
            }
            else if (guess == answer){
                System.out.println("Correct you win!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Math.abs() is the ticket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Random class has another `nextInt(...)` method, one that takes a parameter and that returns a random number between 0 and 1 minus the number passed in. So if you pass in 100, you'll get a pseudo random number between 0 and 99. So just call `r.nextInt(100) + 1` on your Random object, r, to get a number between 1 and 100.

In general, if you want a random number between a and b, you would use

```
r.nextInt(b - a + 1) + a
```

Comment: So I don't need the modulus?

Comment: @MatsMoreau: No. That's what the overload `nextInt(int i)` is for -- to avoid having to worry about modulus and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

```
int answer = Math.abs(r.nextInt());
```

Not best solution, but another possible alternative...when in doubt with negatives...Math.abs() always works :D

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
int answer = r.nextInt(100)
```

instead of

```
int answer = r.nextInt()%101
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer this link
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62

you can refer this program and make use i suppose, give 1 as START and 100 as END, generate and then proceed... 
    import java.util.Random;

```
/** Generate random integers in a certain range. */
public final class RandomRange {

public static final void main(String... aArgs){
log("Generating random integers in the range 1..10.");

int START = 1;
int END = 10;
Random random = new Random();
for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
  showRandomInteger(START, END, random);
}

log("Done.");
}

private static void showRandomInteger(int aStart, int aEnd, Random aRandom){
if (aStart > aEnd) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
}
//get the range, casting to long to avoid overflow problems
long range = (long)aEnd - (long)aStart + 1;
// compute a fraction of the range, 0 <= frac < range
long fraction = (long)(range * aRandom.nextDouble());
int randomNumber =  (int)(fraction + aStart);    
log("Generated : " + randomNumber);
}

private static void log(String aMessage){
System.out.println(aMessage);
}
}
```